# How to pass struct with unsigned char* from C# to C++?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I have some *C++ dll* with struct description and some methods:

```
struct MSG_STRUCT {  
    unsigned long dataSize;
    unsigned char* data;
}
```

And function for example:

```
unsigned long ReadMsg( unsigned long msgId, MSG_STRUCT* readMsg)
{
    readMsg->dataSize = someDataSize;
    readMsg->data = someData;
}
```

So I want to call this function from *C#*:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MSG_STRUCT 
{
    UInt32 dataSize;
    byte[] data;
}

[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
public static Int32 ReadMsg( UInt32 msgId, ref MSG_STRUCT readMsg);
```

So I tried to call *C#* function like:

```
var readMsg = new MSG_STRUCT();
readMsg.data = new byte[4128];
Int32 res = ReadMsg( someMsgId, ref readMsg);
```

But I didn't get smth normal in data.
I also tried to call `ReadMsg` with `IntPrt` type parameter, but `Marshal.PtrToStructure` gave me `AccessViolationException` sometimes.

I don't have any ideas how to pass a pointer to `MSG_STRUCT` from *C#* to *C++* and receive the result as filled `MSG_STRUCT.data`

**The final solutionthat worked for me:**
I used a part of solution offered by xanatos:
I set `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` for my DllImport function.
I found out that I also need to change:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4128)]
public byte[] Data;
```

**Thanks everyone for your help**

Comment: "But i didn't get smth normal in data." What did you get, what were you expecting? Is data supposed to be a string or a byte array?

Comment: Data is supposed to be a byte array.

Answer (score 3):

You could try with:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MSG_STRUCT 
{
    int dataSize;
    IntPtr data;

    public byte[] GetData() 
    {
        var bytes = new byte[dataSize];
        Marshal.Copy(data, bytes, 0, dataSize);
        return bytes;
    }
}

[DllImport("NativeLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern uint ReadMsg(uint msgId, ref MSG_STRUCT readMsg);
```

and then:

```
MSG_STRUCT msg = new MSG_STRUCT();
uint res = ReadMsg(123, ref msg);
byte[] bytes = msg.GetData();
```

Your C function is reassigning the `data` pointer, so you have to marshal it back to C#. The easiest way (for me) is to simply pass a `IntPtr` and do some explicit `Marshal.Copy(...)`.

An alternative is to have `data` a `byte[]`, but then in C-side you have to `memcpy(readMsg->data, someData, someDataSize)`  instead of simply assigning `readMsg->data = someData`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change attribute from

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
```

to

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=X)]
```

Where X is 1,2,4,8 ..

Default packing in c++ is 8, so try to set Pack = 8

Comment: I have edited my answer. It may depend on different packing of structures in C++ and C#.